# Invert y axis on d3 on console command

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

So I'm trying to identify points in a map, I'm doing this by clicking on her and getting the output in the console of X, Y of that dot respectively to my map coordinates, however as we all know the Y axis is not as we are used to it from math lessons and actually starts from the top left corner. I've been googling around for a few hours but I can't find a way to invert the Y axis in order for it to be starting from bottom left corner.

```
<script>
    width = 14990/5,
    height = 15100/5,
    bg = "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/riot-developer-portal/docs/map11.png";


svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("id", "yossi");

svg.append('image')
    .attr('xlink:href', bg)
    .attr('x', '0')
    .attr('y', '0')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

var yossi = document.querySelector('#yossi');

// Get point in global SVG space
function cursorPoint(evt){
  pt = yossi.createSVGPoint();
  pt.x = evt.clientX*5-120; pt.y = evt.clientY*5-120;
  return pt.matrixTransform(yossi.getScreenCTM());
}

yossi.addEventListener('click',function(evt){
  var loc = cursorPoint(evt);
  console.log(loc.x +',' + loc.y);
  // Use loc.x and loc.y here
},false);
</script>
```

This is my javascript file, please help :).

Comment: Be careful. If there's any text, that will end up upside down if you do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invert the y position of the SVG coordinates system to a more conventional, cartesian system (where y grows from bottom to top), just use this simple math:

```
var y = height - yPosition
```

Where `yPosition` is the position using the SVG coordinates system, where y grows from top to bottom.

Here is a basic demo, using `d3.mouse`:

```js
width = 300, height = 100;

svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

svg.on('mousemove', function() {
  var y = height - d3.mouse(this)[1];
  console.log("y position is: " + y);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 20% !important;}

svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lavender;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```